# OnTouch in the style of OnClick

Tags: android, lejos-nxj

I'm trying to implement onTouch in my class used to remote control a mindstorms robot. I've still a lot of work to do, but for now I'm trying to tidy up the direct control which uses onClick. 5 buttons, 5 instantiations like the code below, which calls one of 5 methods containing the instructions for the robot to move.

EDIT:
An Activity has 5 buttons, each does something. The original class used onClickListener as shown below, where they would be instantiated within the OnCreate method calling a void method that had the actual code to perform.

I wanted to use onTouch instead as it makes the remote ...better. But I had a problem trying to get it to work with more than one button.

```
btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);// instantiates a button called
    // btn1 one from the xml
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            driveFore();//move forward

        }// calls the method
    });// end of method
```

This is the original onClick, which calls a method outside the onCreate.

```
private void driveFore() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Motor.A.forward();
    Motor.B.forward();

}//Move forward
```

I would like to do the above, but with onTouch. As it is, once a button is clicked, the motors continue until another button is clicked, so I thought that onTouch would be better since it will only move as long as a button is held down.

And this is the onTouch variant

```
btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn1.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

Which listens for

```
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (event.getAction()) {
     case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            Motor.A.forward();
            Motor.B.forward();
            break;
     case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:{

            Motor.A.flt();
            Motor.B.flt();
    }
    break;
}
    return true;
}
```

The above code works, but only for 1 button. How would I go about applying the above for as many as 5 buttons.

EDIT: 
As suggested I've tried using these two method:

```
            btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                Motor.A.forward();
                Motor.B.forward();
                break;
             case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                Motor.A.flt();
                Motor.B.flt();
             }
            return true;

        }
    });


    btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    btn2.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                Motor.A.forward();
                Motor.B.forward();
                break;
             case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                Motor.A.flt();
                Motor.B.flt();
             }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Works just fine. Thanks guys.

Comment: What do you mean that it only works for 1 button? Have you tried setting the listeners for more than one?

Comment: The onTouch listener is set for btn1. I'm having a problem placing the public boolean ontouch method into a method that can be called, as it would with onClick

Comment: I still don't fully understand the problem, sry.

Comment: I've tried updating the question

Comment: There's no need to duplicate the code like that. Make one listener and connect all 5 buttons to the same one. Either by making your own custom listener, or by overriding the standard one and setting them to "this", as you've done with the first one. Am I making sense?...

Comment: I understand what you mean, but I have no idea how to go about doing it. With the current implementation it just works, regardless of how messy it is. I may have to review it though since its bluetooth, these operations might need to be run in a thread rather than an activity.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9339/discussion-between-keyser5053-and-troothhertz)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to have your Activity extends OnTouchListener.  You can do the same thing with anonymous inner classes.  Like this:

```
btn1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            Motor.A.forward();
            Motor.B.forward();
            break;
         case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            Motor.A.flt();
            Motor.B.flt();
         }
    }
});

btn2.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // Something else here
    }
});
```

Comment: Right, sorry.  The return is a boolean that tells whether the touch event was handled here or not.  If you return false, it will try to bubble the touch even up to the next level element.